# What is considered the "canonical" way to make data changes in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've spent a good amount of time getting up to speed with the norms of Jetpack Compose application development.

I've put together a sample scenario which outlines how I tend to make things currently that's working for me, but leaves me with some questions.  Specifically around how I have changes propagate from components up to a parent component responsible for saving data.

```kotlin
data class OuterState(val innerState: InnerState, val outerValue: String)
data class InnerState(val innerValue: String)

@HiltViewModel
class OuterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    // ...
) : ViewModel() {

    suspend fun saveData(someValue: OuterState) {
        // note: Save `someValue`...
    }
}

@Composable
fun OuterComponent(
    viewModel: OuterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

    var outerState by remember { mutableStateOf(OuterState(
        outerValue = "outer-value",
        innerState = InnerState(
            innerValue = "inner-value",
        ),
    )) }

    LaunchedEffect(outerState) {
        viewModel.saveData(outerState)
    }

    InnerComponent(
        outerState.innerState,
        {
            outerState = outerState.copy(innerState = it)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun InnerComponent(
    initialValue: InnerState,
    onChange: (newValue: InnerState) -> Unit,
) {

    var innerState by remember(initialValue) { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }

    LaunchedEffect(innerState) {
        onChange(innerState)
    }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            innerState = innerState.copy(innerValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        },
    ) {

        Text("Do Thing")
    }
}
```

Notes:

- As you can see, new is reflected within `InnerComponent` before the save is even triggered.
- I'm using `LaunchedEffect` to track when to act on changed data.
- When `initialData` comes back, I'm aware that it could potentially override any accumulated state on the component.
- Based on how this is done, the UI can reflect changes immediately without having to wait for the network to come back.

Questions:

- Is there anything that's overall inadvisable handling changes in this way?
- It clearly doesn't respect a uni-directional data flow as I'm mutating my data within the component *as well as* sending it up to the caller *and then also* flowing data back down potentially after save.  Is this a problem?
- Can I simplify anything?

Comment: What is the use of having inner state and outer state? If the state is required in the ViewModel, the state can be in the ViewModel and passed to the Composables from there, maintaining a single source of truth.

Comment: They're different types.

Answer (score 2):

```
InnerComponent(
        outerState.innerState,
        {
            outerState = outerState.copy(innerState = it)
        }
)
```

doesn't look right.

You should observe the state from ViewModel (it can be the same ViewModel or a different one) in a similar way as you are getting it in outer component.

The `onChange` callback should also only call ViewModel's method to do some work and update the state inside ViewModel's code.

Components should only observe and render the state and call ViewModel's functions on any events.

Comment: Good insights, thanks!  So what if I want to do like my example and have a component responsible for just a subset of the overall state?  You'll notice that I have an instance of `InnerState` as a property on my `OuterState`.  And that's what the `InnerComponent` is responsible for manipulating and returning.

Should I really be waiting for everything to resolve all the way up to the view model before updating my `InnerComponent`?

Comment: Perhaps something like this? https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/460cf9098c9950c7b133551408a26f64#file-2-kt

Comment: "Should I really be waiting for everything to resolve all the way up to the view model" - I think that's how it's supposed to work in the MVVM approach.. ViewModel is responsible for storing and changing data. Also if you will pass a reference to ViewModel into InnerState, it's a direct call.

Comment: Right, but what if say for example my save also performs an expensive network operation.  The user shouldn't have to wait for the save to complete before seeing their changes.  It should just happen in the background, right?

Comment: Yeah, in this case you can, for example, emit optimistic response instantly to update the state from ViewModel. After getting an actual response you can emit the view state again accounting for possible errors.

Comment: And that "response" could just be to update my mutable flow with a new value?

Comment: Yeah, you are right